# S3 via CloudFront always gives me AccessDenied message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

As much as it's easy to set up Amazon Cloudfront for custom origins, it is giving me a hard time in setting it up for S3 origins.

Regardless how I change my settings, when trying to access S3 object via CloudFront, it gives me AccessDenied message.

I'm using CloudFront for a full site delivery. So the URL I intend to use and the one I'm getting AWS AccessDenied message on is:

http://www.mydomainname.com/imagefile/live/media/medium/06904976c744edf870db308a08320284.JPG

The direct S3 URL for the object is below and it works fine:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket-name/live/media/medium/06904976c744edf870db308a08320284.JPG

**Cloudfront Origin Settings:**

[image: Cloudfront Origin Settings:]

**Cloufront Behaviour Settings:**
[image: Cloufront Behaviour Settings:]

S3 Policy (of course instead of "my-s3-bucket-name" there is a real bucket name used).

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name/live/bk/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name/live/media/medium/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name/live/media/thumb/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name/live/media/thumb_v2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The filename used in the URL itself has "Everyone" as a grantee with open/download permissions.

Can somebody spot where the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths you requesting aren't the same, can you try requesting the same path you used directly to s3 but with the CloudFront provided DNS name?

CloudFront:
/imagefile/live/media/medium/06904976c744edf870db308a08320284.JPG

S3:
/live/media/medium/06904976c744edf870db308a08320284.JPG

Comment: Why would you say that the paths aren't the same? /imagefile is hooked up directly to the root origin bucket. I've tried using original CloudFront URL, but I get the same AccessDenied message. http://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/imagefile/live/media/medium/06904976c744edf870db308a08320284.JPG.
By skipping "imagefile" it doesn't even route to S3.

Comment: I mean the paths are not the same. CloudFront is a proxy, unless you are using origin+path, it's not modifying the path. If /live/ isn't going to s3, you may need to setup a cache behavior to match /live/* and use your s3 origin. Your /imagesfile/ cache behavior doesn't point to the root of your s3 bucket, it points to yourbucket/imagefiles/.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Because of some reason I was under impression that /imagesfile didn't have to exist on S3 and it would point to root. I was wrong. After modifying the cache behaviour to match the pattern of "live/*" I'm now able to successfully access files in my S3 via Cloudfront. Thanks!

Comment: What was the cache behavior modification? I have the same problem now.